# How to change Datum to WGS 84?

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, datum, everest-1830

I have a shapefile with following projection information:

PROJCS["kl2",GEOGCS["kl3",DATUM["D_Everest_1830",SPHEROID["Everest_1830",6377299.36,300.8017]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Polyconic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",76.5],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",8.5],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

How can I convert this datum to WGS 1984?

Comment: @underdark I'm not sure this is a duplicate, or at least not to the listed. This crs is custom, so it has no wkid, also datum/geocrs is unidentified, so there's no oblivious transformation.

Answer (score 1):

If the projection information is from the .prj file of the shapefile bundle, you can simply run

```
ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 dst_datasource_name src_datasource_name
```

If the shapefile lacks the .prj file, put the given string in a text file, and save it as `name.prj` where name is the same as in `name.shp`.

Note that coordinates that are stored in the attribute table will not get reprojected.

Answer (score 0):

Since the original is in everest, simple transformation will shift the result from actual position in wgs around 200m.

The system is polyconic so you will have to ask the local gis experts for transformation parameters. If it were in transverse mercator i could provide the parameter i use.